# How do ProxyPass from Apache to node.js so I can drop the port number in my local URL?

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx, node.js, proxypass, localhost

I'm trying to use a domain name for local development of a next.js app. Normally, it fires up at `localhost:3000` but I'd like to use `site1.local` (and no port).

I've edited my hosts files to point the new domain at `127.0.0.1` and I've turned on `vhosts` and have the following config using `ProxyPass` to use apache to pass through to the node server.

`/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin me@example.org
        ServerName site1.local

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin me@example.org
        ServerName site2.local

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `site1.local` I get a white screen. However, when I visit `site1.local:3000` I can see the website fine. So I believe that means apache is working and the hosts file is working, but my vhost config is maybe not. I'm not that familiar with `ProxyPass` so there might also be some config I'm missing. Most guides I've found follow this.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Here are my enabled apache modules from httpd.conf file:

```
#LoadModule mpm_event_module libexec/apache2/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module libexec/apache2/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module libexec/apache2/mod_mpm_worker.so
LoadModule authn_file_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module libexec/apache2/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module libexec/apache2/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module libexec/apache2/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule socache_shmcb_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule socache_redis_module libexec/apache2/mod_socache_redis.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module libexec/apache2/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule macro_module libexec/apache2/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module libexec/apache2/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module libexec/apache2/mod_echo.so
#LoadModule buffer_module libexec/apache2/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule data_module libexec/apache2/mod_data.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module libexec/apache2/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module libexec/apache2/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule reflector_module libexec/apache2/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule substitute_module libexec/apache2/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module libexec/apache2/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module libexec/apache2/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module libexec/apache2/mod_xml2enc.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule ldap_module libexec/apache2/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule logio_module libexec/apache2/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime_magic.so
#LoadModule expires_module libexec/apache2/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module libexec/apache2/mod_usertrack.so
##LoadModule unique_id_module libexec/apache2/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module libexec/apache2/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_uwsgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_uwsgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_fdpass_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fdpass.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule proxy_hcheck_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_hcheck.so
#LoadModule session_module libexec/apache2/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_plain.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule dialup_module libexec/apache2/mod_dialup.so
#LoadModule http2_module libexec/apache2/mod_http2.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
##LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache2/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    #LoadModule cgid_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    #LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
#LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache2/mod_imagemap.so
#LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache2/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache2/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
#LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
```

Comment: anything useful inside the apache logs ? besides, since apache and node.js resides on the same server, I believe when typing site1.local:3000 , you bypass apache completely and connect directly to node.js

Comment: what's the response to `http://site1.local/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was a conflict with Kestrel Server. Stopping the other server worked with the above configuration